# All my downloaded files are opening in emacs. How can I fix this?

Tags: browser, emacs, ubuntu-11.04

If I download something in Google Chrome or in Firefox and then click on that file to open it, it opens in Emacs. How can I fix this? Even if I click on "Show in folder", then too, the folder opens up in Emacs. The PDFs are opening in Emacs.

I want them to open in whatever software is set in default "Open with" properties. For example I want downloaded PDFs to open in Document viewer. "Show in Folder" to open in Nautilus, etc.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04, btw.

Comment: Get rid of emacs and use `vi`/`vim` instead. ;)

Comment: How would that help? User wants to open PDFs?! I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You system install is messed up. Try creating a new user, lauch firefox, download anything, and open it. See ?

If you *must* keep this current user, then launch a file explorer, then right-click on files and choose "open with..." then "Use this to open this file type".